# Calling JavaScript function on division(bootstrap modal popup)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modalpopup

I have a JavaScript function and would like it to be called when using the bootstrap's modal popup.
However, the function isn't called at all. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      /*---------------------------------------------About Us-----------------------------------------------*/
      function aboutUs(AU) {
          $("#modal-content").window({
                  icon: ('/SAFETY_AT_SG/Images/PopUpWindowImg/Analysis.png'),
                  title: "About Us",
                  content: "<div>" +
            "<h3>Our Vision and Mission</h3>" +
            "<img src='..Images/Logo.jpg' />" +
            "<h5>Our Vision</h5>" +
            "<p>Create safety awareness among Teenagers to Adults</p>" +
            "<h5>Our Mission</h5>" +
            "<p>- Develop an Online Map Portal/Mobile Platform which serve as a purpose for adults to <br/>identify the safety issue around a area.</p>" +
            "<p>- Provide kids/teenagers the safer/shortest route to travel back home avoiding any <br/>unncessary trouble." +
            "</div>",

              });
      }
</script>
```

This is where I called the function.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="About" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>About Us</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    aboutUs(this);
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone correct my code?

Comment: add the call to the jquery document ready or the docs onload event

Comment: hi i dont get what you mean. can you provide me a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your script with `$( document ).ready()` or move it to the bottom of the code!

Comment: sorry , can you provide me a sample? I am new to javascript and I really have no idea..

Comment: Here is one [example][1]                                              [1]: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

*A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside **$( document ).ready()** will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.*

So your code would change to this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="About" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>About Us</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        aboutUs(this);
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I did that but I am not getting error.. and nothing is shown

Comment: I think you need to give more detail for us to help further. for example bootstrap uses `$(selector).modal(options)` to show modals; what made you call *window* `$(selector).widow(options)`? Also do you know how to debug javascript in the browser? You should really learn how to do this chrome and IE both have dev tools accessed via the F12 key. If you use the keyword `debugger` with the dev tool open it will break at the point you have the keyword. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript